# Irreducible factors of polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}[X]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-fields, irreducible-polynomials

I know how to compute the irreducible factor of polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ where $p$ is prime over $\mathbb{F}_p[X]$. There is even a formula to know how many factors of each degree there are.

How can I study the irreducible factors of polynomial $X^{p^n}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_{p^i}[X]$ with $i> 0$

**An example**

Say I want to compute the irreducible factorization of $X^{16}-X$ over $\mathbb{F}_4$. I already know that over $\mathbb{F}_2$ this is $X(X-1)(X^2+X+1)(X^4+X^3+1)(X^4+X+1)(X^4+X^3+X^2+X+1)$.

[This other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679265/factoring-x16-x-over-mathbbf-8) claims that the factorization over $\mathbb{F}_4$ contains only factors of degree 1 or 2. Why is it the case?

Comment: I'm guessing you mean $\Bbb F_{p^{\large i}}[X]$. | The splitting field of $X^{16}-X$ is $\Bbb F_{16}$ which is a degree $2$ extension of $\Bbb F_4$, that's why the factors of $X^{16}-X$ are all degree $1$ or $2$ over $\Bbb F_4$.

Comment: The factors of $X^{p^n}-X$ over $\Bbb{F}_p$ are precisely the irreducible polynomials in $\Bbb{F}_p[X]$ of degree $d$ such that $d\mid n$. They all appear exactly once. An irreducible polynomial of degree $d$ in $\Bbb{F}_p[x]$ splits into a product of $\gcd(d,m)$ irreducible factors of degree $d/\gcd(d,m)$ in $\Bbb{F}_{p^m}[x]$.

Comment: Not trivial, but does follow from the Galois theory of finite fields. It has been handled on our site. Gimme a minute.

Comment: [This](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/86778/11619) is probably a good starting point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to proof that if I have an irreducible polynomial over $\mathbb{F}_{p}$ then over $\mathbb{F}^m$ its irreducible factors (if any) must all have same degree. The proof follows [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86778/why-does-an-irreducible-polynomial-split-into-irreducible-factors-of-equal-degre). Basically I write $f = \prod q_i$ and take $\alpha$ a root of $q_1$, $\beta$ a root of $q_i$. Then since $f$ is irreducible we know that $Gal(f/\mathbb{F}_{p})$ must be a transitive subgroup and therefore there exists $\sigma$ in this group such that $\sigma(\alpha) = \beta)$.

Then the extended $\sigma$ to polynomials gives $\overline{\sigma}(q_1) = h$ such that $h$ is irreducible, $\beta$ is a root of $h$ and $deg(h) = deg(q_1)$. Therefore $q_i | h$ and $deg(q_i) \le deg(q_1)$. Changing the roles of the elements implied should give the other inequality.

For showing that they the same degree one proceeds as follows. We take a root of $f$, $\alpha$. Then $$n = [\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p] = [\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^m} \cap \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)][\mathbb{F}_{p^m} \cap \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p]$$

Now one uses what sometimes is called the Natural Irrationalities Theorem. Basically we want $[\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^m} \cap \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)] = [\mathbb{F}_{p^m}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^m}]$.

In general, if $L/F$ is Galois and $K/F$ finite then $Gal(KL/K) \cong Gal(L/K \cap L)$. Above we just take $K = \mathbb{F}_{p^m}$ and $L = \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha)$.

Therefore, $$n = [\mathbb{F}_{p^m}(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_{p^m}][\mathbb{F}_{p^m} \cap \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p]$$ Where the first part is precisely the degree of the irreducible polynomials $q_i$ therefore, now $[\mathbb{F}_{p^m} \cap \mathbb{F}_p(\alpha):\mathbb{F}_p]$ is precisely the degree of the irreducible polynomials of the extensions. We can take $\mathbb{F}_p(\alpha) \cong \mathbb{F}_{p^d}$ and therefore the intersection is $\mathbb{F}_{p^{gcd(d,m)}}$ and therefore $n = gcd(m,d)d$.

In my case, this leads to $4 = gcd(2,d)d$. Since $gcd(2,d) = 1,2$, possible solutions should verify $4 = 2d$ or $4 = d$. however $4$ is not a solution. Therefore, it has to be $d = 2$.

I wonder if the fact that finite fields are perfect fields can be exploited in some way...

For instance, I think that one could use that the Galois group of the extension $\mathbb{F}_{p^n}/\mathbb{F}_p$ is generated by the Frobenius automorphism $\phi$ to proof that all factors have the same number of zeros...